# Author card content is truncated in the blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog

In the recent blog post titled [The path to socially responsible AI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/01/18/the-path-to-socially-responsible-ai), the content within the author card appears truncated, concluding with an ellipsis. Unfortunately, there is no tooltip available for readers to access the complete content.

The provided screenshot in the developer console displays the full content.
[image: Truncated author card]

Currently, the author card exhibits only the initial three lines of the content. In this scenario, the absence of a tooltip necessitates its implementation. Alternatively, removing the `-webkit-line-clamp: 3` would present the entire content without truncation.
[image: Full author card]

Comment: That's not a user card, and can't see how it's related to tooltips. However it's a bug in the design of the blog - so those are the proper tags.

Comment: Also worth to mention, the author of the blog post [has account here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1411606/ryan-polk) however it's blank, no information whatsoever.

Comment: I reached out to our team that maintains the blog to get some eyes on this. It's late on a Friday so might not hear back until next week.

Comment: @David the actual bug is still there, the data is still truncated. I see it now links to a blog profile page, which is awesome, but maybe mark this is [tag:status-bydesign] and explain that's the design of the blog? (i.e. truncated about me info leading to the full bio when clicked.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On January 2024 profiles were added to the blog, and now it's possible to click the author card to read the full bio, e.g. [the profile for Ryan](https://stackoverflow.blog/author/ryan-polk/).

This does give a way to see the whole content, however it's still truncated and without tooltip showing all of it, so I disagree with the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) that was assigned to the bug.

Technically, this is by design, as the bug is not reporting missing profile but only truncated text.